# Change Shape Colour when Cell is Clicked

Tags: excel, colors, shapes, choropleth, vba

I am looking for some code that will change the colour of a shape when a cell is clicked on. 
Example the shape is S_IRL which is Ireland and is located in Cell B22.

What I would like to happen is that if Cell B22 then shape S_IRL changes from Blue to Red. Then if another cell with a country is clicked then the corresponding shape changes to red and the previous returns to it previous colour. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new subroutine in the worksheet's code that will fire when the selection changes on the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim strShapeName As String 'Variable to hold the shape name
    Dim shp As Shape 'Variable to hold a shape object

    'Detect if the click was in range A:C
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:C")) Is Nothing Then

        'Boom... set all the shapes to blue
        For Each shp In Me.Shapes
             If Left(shp.Name, 2) = "S_" Then shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Next shp        

        'Grab the shape name from Column A
        strShapeName = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value

        'Set the color of the shape to red
        Shapes(strShapeName).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

This will detect if the selection change was to a cell in columns A, B, or C. If it was it will grab the name of the shape from Column A and then set the color of that shape to red.

Comment: You never set the previous selected shape back to it's old color.

Comment: @JNevill Not sure if you saw OldUgly's comment since he didn't tag you in the comment, but you didn't provide code to return to the original color once another selection is made.

Comment: Yea it seems I left that out. Hard to write on mobile

Comment: @JNevill I am also curious why you would have the user create a new column with the shape name since in his example he shows that it already exists in column A? If there is a correspondence that is required, why not just modify column A (and your code accordingly)?

Comment: Oh yea! it is already there. Back now. Writing the rest of this mess.

Comment: Hi Guys, This was such great peice of work to come into this morning. It really really helped. Thank you so much for your time and expertise.